# How to do an ElasticSearch using REST request body method and get the returned json formatted / pretty?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch.net

In issuing a search request, via REST Request Body method, such as

```
GET /bank/_search
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} },
  "sort": [
    { "account_number": "asc" }
  ]
}
```

is there a parameter that can be added anywhere to request the returned response body's json be formatted/pretty ?

The same search using `REST Request URI` enables to do that, like

```
GET /bank/_search?q=*&sort=account_number:asc&pretty
```

How to achieve the same using `REST request body` ?

Using ElasticSearch.NET's low level api, one have no control over the REST call, and can only provide the POST json.

```
var esClient = new ElasticLowLevelClient(_connectionSettings);
//postDataJson is the json depicted in the question's body
var postData = PostData.String(postDataJson); 
var response = esClient.Search<StringResponse>("myIndex", postData);
```

One can send a third parameter, a `SearchRequestParameters` object, I can't find any property there for that.

[image]

Comment: I am purposely not using Newtonsoft.Json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add to your request `pretty=true`
Like that:

```
GET /bank/_search?q=*&sort=account_number:asc&pretty=true
```

for more reference check [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html)

### **EDIT**

I didn't understand you at first, the pretty should be in the header of the request.
Try like that:

```
GET /bank/_search?pretty=true
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} },
  "sort": [
    { "account_number": "asc" }
  ]
}
```

### **EDIT 2**

If you are using **elstic.NET** and you want too achieve pretty Jason.
You need to configure it in **the connection**.
Here is the method you should use(it's in the class`ConnectionConfiguration : ConnectionConfiguration<ConnectionConfiguration>)`:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Forces all requests to have ?pretty=true querystring parameter appended,
    /// causing Elasticsearch to return formatted JSON.
    /// Also forces the client to send out formatted JSON. Defaults to <c>false</c>
    /// </summary>
    public T PrettyJson(bool b = true) => Assign(a =>
    {
        this._prettyJson = b;
        const string key = "pretty";
        if (!b && this._queryString[key] != null) this._queryString.Remove(key);
        else if (b && this._queryString[key] == null)
            this.GlobalQueryStringParameters(new NameValueCollection { { key, "true" } });
    });
```

Here you can see the [git](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Elasticsearch.Net/Configuration/ConnectionConfiguration.cs)

Comment: You are showing how I do that using the REST Request URI method, I want to know how I do the same via REST Request body (by the way, it is not necessary to assign "true" to pretty, as far as I recall)

Comment: I edited the answer, hope it would help. about the true, you are correct - I didn't know it is not necessary to assign true.

Comment: Well, (I believe, not sure) I asked the question with ElasticSearch.NET low level api in mind. using ElasticSearch.net (low level) api. One has no control over the REST call itself. Try to do that with ElasticSearchClient. I edited the question. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Why don't you work with Nest? there, I know for a fact it exist.  (I can update with nest example if you will need)

Comment: I added the method you should use, Your mistake is that you looked in the search when you actually need to use the pretty jason on the connection

Comment: I am not using Nest because I did not like the requirement of having to define POCO classes for all the document types I am going to search for. This requires a lot of work! I then opted for the low level api, where I will work with the response jsons and that's it.

Comment: You did a great job I must say, quite determined to solve it :)

Comment: Haha, It became personal.